# iOS 9: How to access UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey without error 257?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

My `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method stores a filename from the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` and tries to open it.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSURL* url = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
    NSError* err;
    if ([url checkResourcesIsReachableAndReturnError:&err])
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

For iOS 8 this code works fine. My application is launched because some other application selected "open in" to my application, but for iOS 9 this code doesn't work, and I get

> err = NSCocoaErrorDomain : code 257 : "The file 'XXX' couldn't be
>   opened because you don't have permission to view it."
>
> "The operation couldn't be completed. Operation not permitted"

**Very important note**: This only happens when my application was shut down while the user tried to open a file from another application. I see that the file that is being sent in UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey is indeed located not in the same sandbox as my application is. If it was not shut down, just minimized, everything behaves well because the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey is in the same sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem in iOS 9 beta 3 that was resolved in beta 4.

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method was triggered with a filepath in the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey that was in a different application's space, hence it was sandboxed and the iOS application could not access it.

Anyhow Apple now resolved this issue.